# How to find highest value in adjacent column and paste the name and the value to another range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like

[tABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qdC1.png)

A list of the name in the first column and a list of there score each time. I want to find each players highest score and paste it to another place.

End result should be
[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jm0e.png)

This is a simpliefied version of what I have but is essentially the same thing, I am using this within a vba project but happy to use formulas and get the macro to fill them in.

Comment: Without looking at the images, index() with match() does this well usually.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-maxifs-function